# SSMS agent job using scp command to transfer files to sftp is going to loop and not completing

Tags: perl, ssms-2012

Have tried different approaches to make the SSMs job working with SCP command with perl script. but the job is going into loop with out having a result.
PS : The script is working fine with running from command prompt directly.

command used in the perl script:-

```
$Command = "scp -i D:\File1\RS2\DataFeed\Code\PrivateKey.ppk -s $InternalFile admin@sftp.world.com:$VendorName/$DestFileName";
```

system command used in perl

```
system($command);
```

While running the command directly from windows cmd it is correctly placing file to the SFTP. but while running this perl script from ssms agent job it seems not working and the job is keep running without any results.
Any possible leads to the actual errors will be much appreciated

Detailed Steps :

Job in SSMS : [image]

Step : [image]

DataFeed.cmd

```html
%_Debug% echo off


cd /d %0\.. 
pushd .
setlocal

rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem Localize environment
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------

if exist DataFeed_Environment.cmd (
    call DataFeed_Environment.cmd
) else (
    echo DataFeed_Environment.cmd not found!!!
    echo
    goto CmdUsage
)



rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem Run perl package
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe DataFeedProd1.pl
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto ErrorExit

goto Exit

rem -----------------------------------------------------
rem Command Usage
rem -----------------------------------------------------
:CmdUsage
    Echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo.
    echo DataFeed.cmd
    echo  Wraps the call to DataFeed.pl,
    echo  mails log upon errors.
    echo.
    echo Usage:
    echo DataFeed.cmd
    echo.
    echo ----------------------------------
rem endlocal
rem popd
rem exit 1


rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem Error exit
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
:ErrorExit
echo DataFeedProd1.pl failed !!!
echo 
rem endlocal
rem popd
rem exit  1


rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem Exit
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem endlocal
rem popd
:Exit

rem exit  0
```

```html
sub CopyDataFeedFileToSftp{

   my ($DataFeedFileInternal, $DataFeedVendorName,$DataFeedFileName) = @_;
   my($DestFileName)=$DataFeedFileName.".zip";
   my($Command);
   my($RetValue) = 1;

   $Command = "C:\\Users\\hprasu\\Downloads\\OpenSSH-Win64\\scp.exe -i D:\\File1\\RS2\\DataFeed\\Code\\PrivateKey.ppk -s $DataFeedFileInternal a_Tne\@nasftp\.egencia.com:$DataFeedVendorName/$DestFileName";
   $RetVal = &CallSystem($Command);
   if ($RetVal == 0) {
      &AppendFileToLog($TempFile);
      &ErrorExit("Unable to copy data feed file using SCP command:\n".$Command);
   }
}
```

The above perl method is executing the System command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

- have full path to perl.exe and your perl script in job's command
- escape all special characters in interpolated strings for Perl and
- use full path for scp command since
  operating system don't know where  scp.exe is located (until it in the  $PATH):
- check filesystem permissions for all files in the command and perl script. Job should has access those files.

So command would be

```
$Command = "full_path\\scp.exe -i D:\\File1\\RS2\\DataFeed\\Code\\PrivateKey.ppk -s $InternalFile admin\@sftp.world.com:$VendorName/$DestFileName";
```

Read this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-quoted-interpolated-and-escaped-strings/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I even tried this and still not been able to successfully executed from SSMS job. Although it is running successfully by executing the script directly. am not sure if am missing any permission in SSMS to execute SCP commands or something like that.

Comment: @harun prasu  Answer updated

Comment: tried by giving full path to scp also, still the same the SSMS job keep on running

Comment: `$Command = "C:\\Users\\hprasu\\Downloads\\OpenSSH-Win64\\scp.exe -i D:\\File1\\RS2\\DataFeed\\Code\\PrivateKey.ppk -s $DataFeedFileInternal admin\@sftp.world.com:$DataFeedVendorName/$DestFileName";`

Comment: Check  what account ssms job is running under  and this accaount has filesystem permissions to all files from your command command.

Comment: Checked file system permission for the the sql server agent user and confirmed the user has access to both the locations

Comment: Your job use perl to run script so you should have full path to perl.exe in job's command

Comment: What is -s option for scp? Cant find in docs. If its a filename check permissions too

Comment: this command is running inside the perl script using the system($command) and -s option is the source directory which I checked and made sure the sql server agent user has permission. That's why it is confusing me to check if there are any additional steps need to be taken care while running scp command inside perl from SSMS job. and it is even confusing as the command works by double clicking the perl script.

Comment: In job you should have somthing like pathtoperl\perl.exe pathtoscript\script.pl

Comment: have given full path to perl in the ssms job as well. same issue :(

Comment: Provide screenshots like here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/create-and-schedule-a-job-in-sql-server-2008  so i can check them

Comment: @harun prasu  Also post whole perl script too

Comment: Thank you, I have added more details in the answer including the method used in perl. but couldnt post the entire perl script as it is having more number of lines. the method itself is calling a Sytem commad and do nothing else.

Comment: Again: at least use full path for everthing: DataFeedProd1.pl DataFeed_Environment.cmd and whatever inside these scripts. Does whole DataFeed.cmd work from cmd running by hand?

Comment: I have tried that aswell, It's just the example provided was not having that full path. Yes DataFeed.cmd is running fine when executing it by double clicking

Comment: I figured out the issue. The issue was with the ssh file the SSMS job rely on. The job was running as sql server agent service account and the service account user needs to have a .ssh folder with known_host file in it which should have the ssh private key. I have copied the .ssh folder from my user account to that service account users folder and it worked !!!